# SQL (String+Int) Variables Insert Loop

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1292

iam trying to add multi records into a table using that code

```
BEGIN
    SET @i:=10000;
    WHILE @i <= 10099 DO
        INSERT INTO wp_genpro_products (serial, guarantee) VALUES ('HMAX'+@i, 0);
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

it works fine with only numbers without the add of `'HMAX'+` but when tried to insert letters with the numbers it gives me #1292 error - truncated incorrect double value

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_genpro_products` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `serial` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `guarantee` mediumint(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_date` date DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: You should add a definition of your table so we can see the column type and length

Comment: What is the data type for the field ```serial```?  It appears that it will not allow character values.

Comment: it's varchar(255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by using `CONCAT()`

```
BEGIN
    SET @i:=10000;
    WHILE @i <= 10099 DO
        INSERT INTO wp_genpro_products (serial, guarantee) VALUES (CONCAT('HMAX',@i), 0);
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```